# How do you configure Perl CPAN in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, perl, package-management, cpan

I can't seem to get CPAN installs working on a Solaris machine. Here is my current output.

```
~# perl -MCPAN -eshell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.7601)
ReadLine support available (try 'install Bundle::CPAN')

cpan> install Bundle::LWP                 
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
LWP not available
CPAN: Net::FTP loaded ok
Fetching with Net::FTP:
  ftp://ftp.dti.ad.jp/pub/lang/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Couldn't fetch 01mailrc.txt.gz from ftp.dti.ad.jp
...
...
```

This output is repeated for every mirror. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few possibilities of what it could be, but the most typical issue is that you're behind a firewall that requires you to use passive FTP.  You can either look for an HTTP mirror, or try setting the environmental variable FTP_PASSIVE to a true value before running cpan.

Comment: export FTP_PASSIVE=1

Comment: Yes, this was it. I ended up figuring this out before I saw your post. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As root

```
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/bin/perlgcc -MCPAN -e shell
```

seems to have done the trick for me. I am on solaris 10 update 6 on sparc.